Changing git commit author
Asking this question now because I could not find a discussion for this exact issue.
Ever since the new year, I realized none of my commits on github were tracking after switching to linux, and I saw that it was because of my git config user.email was improperly set. After I set it to the correct email associated with my github account, I still could not track the changes. Now, today, I found that github gives you an email that you can tie to your user.email on your machine to have github track your commits. All that to say, is it possible, without using rebase and/or reset, to ammend an old commit's author? It's not that big of a deal, I just have 100's of untracked commits I would like to be properly displayed for recruiters that see my profile.
Any help with this would be great, thanks.
See above For the detailed explanation.
